# Я (-) за отмену крепостного права. Я (-) против деспотизма.

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире в следующих случаях: 
Я (-) за отмену крепостного права. 
Я (-) против деспотизма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хочется интонационно выделить это "я" — ставьте тире. Нет — значит, не ставьте. Все здесь очень просто, заумные словеса — от лукавого.

Answer (score 2):

В этих случаях используется **авторское (факультативное) решение**, при этом его можно проверить с помощью интонации. При постановке тире **первое слово выделяется логическим ударением, а после него следует пауза.** При отсутствии тире ударением выделяется вторая часть предложения, паузы нет.

При постановке тире мы обычно имеем продолжение ранее начатой темы, например:

**Я** может быть, вообще против этого! **Я** ― за отмену смертной казни!

Я, наоборот… **я**― левый, **я** - за революцию.

Другие примеры: О чём ты думаешь? Я против, ты слышишь меня? А его всегда козлом считал. Я за идею!

Возможные решения: Как известно, я за отмену крепостного права.

Что касается меня, то мое решение неизменно: я - за отмену крепостного права.

Comment: >> *В этих случаях используется авторское (факультативное) решение, при этом его можно проверить с помощью интонации.* Не решение о тире можно проверить с помощью интонации, а наоборот. Ну, а уж "продолжение начатой темы" вообще притянуто за уши. Странно, что вы простые вещи объясняете так заумно и путано. Достаточно пары фраз: "Допустимы оба варианта. Если первое слово хочется выделить, то ставится тире".

Comment: У нас, по-видимому,  просто разные взгляды на орфографию. Дело не в авторском разрешенном произволе, то есть  интуитивном желании делать или не делать паузу, а в том, что пауза (и тире) меняют расстановку логических ударений и смещают смысловые акценты. А выразить смысл как можно точнее - это и есть очень важная авторская задача.

Comment: Sibylla, абсолютно согласен с вами.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за понимание.

Comment: *У нас, по-видимому, просто разные взгляды на орфографию.* - не мудрено, если вы называете "орфографией" вопрос о постановке тире. Да, орфография в широком смысле - это и пунктуация тоже, но не в таком же узком вопросе. Впрочем, в одном согласен.  Подобные рекомендации Niemand'а можете сразу игнорировать. Несерьезно. Объяснять это ему не обязательно. Имхо.

Comment: Теперь по сути. *Дело не ... в интуитивном желании делать или не делать паузу, а в том, что пауза (и тире) меняют расстановку логических ударений и смещают смысловые акценты.* - Вы немного тут запутались. Именно интонационные паузы - и знаки их маркирующие - и есть то средство, которое помогает понять места логических ударений. Так что ваш спор - на тему, *что правильнее: "в лоб"  или "по лбу"*. А вот как вы представляете иное, т .е. ***противопоставляете** паузы и смысловые акценты*, я решительно не понял.

Comment: *Да, орфография в широком смысле - это и пунктуация тоже* Блеск. Это надо к Задорнову! *Подобные рекомендации Niemand'а можете сразу игнорировать* Яволь, херр начальник!

Comment: Я не противопоставляю паузы и акценты (места логических ударений) , они взаимосвязаны и составляют единую интонационную структуру предложения. Также следует отметить, что интонация совместно  с грамматикой являются ФОРМОЙ предложения, которая выражает определенное СОДЕРЖАНИЕ/СМЫСЛ. Поэтому "наоборот" не получится: содержание управляет формой, автор подбирает форму (интонацию и грамматику), чтобы  выразить определенное содержание.

Comment: И немного о постановке тире при развитии темы: "Писательство – не ремесло и не занятие. Писательство – призвание." В этом примере постановка тире в первом предложении  факультативна, но мы должны логически выделить подлежащее, тема которого продолжена во втором предложении. Это пример взаимосвязи акцентов и пауз.